# Accessing base class members with incorrect downcast in C++

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Is the following C++ code correct?

```
struct Base { int x; };
struct Derived : Base { int y; }
Base * b = new Base;
Derived * d = static_cast<Derived *>(b);
//below we access only d->x, but not d->y
std::cout << d->x;
```

If not, what exactly is wrong? What C++ standard say about this? At least I have not seen it ever crashed.

Comment: `x` and `y` are private here.

Comment: `Base b = new Base;` gives you a `Base`.  You can't just magically get a `Derived` out of it.

Comment: And just because this simple example works doesn't mean you can rely on it working for other cases.

Comment: The rules for when a `static_cast` is well defined can be found here : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast

Comment: @NathanOliver actually question is not so obvious, OP mention that he only going to access `Base` members through `d`

Comment: This works because the common layout has the derived class after the base class in memory. But the compiler could behave differently. Besides, this is a trap waiting to spring. The next coder in line may not notice the Derived is not safe to use.

Comment: Regardless of how `Base` and `Derived` are laid out in memory, the compiler knows how they are related to each other, and how it needs to adjust a `Derived` pointer so it can reach a `Base` object to access its members. And since `d` does not point at a valid `Derived` object, that adjustment will result in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is reasonably straightforward in [[expr.static.cast]/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#11) (emphasis mine):

> **A prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 B”, where B is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv2 D”, where D is a class derived from B**, if cv2 is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv1. If B is a virtual base class of D or a base class of a virtual base class of D, or if no valid standard conversion from “pointer to D” to “pointer to B” exists ([conv.ptr]), the program is ill-formed. The null pointer value is converted to the null pointer value of the destination type. **If the prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 B” points to a B that is actually a subobject of an object of type D, the resulting pointer points to the enclosing object of type D. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**

You don't have a subobject of a `Derived`, so it's undefined behaviour.

---

Note there are no special cases for lvalue or xvalue pointers, and /8 mentions that the operand undergoes an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.